# Chrome Extension Creation - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**content.js:**
`chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'http://www.sethjfreeman.com' });`

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Secure Video Downloader",
    "description": "Download Videos Virus Free",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [
                         {
                             "matches": ["https://gostream.is/*", "http://gostream.is/*"],
                             "js": ["content.js", "jquery-3.2.1.min.js"],
                             "run_at": "document_end"
                         }
                  ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "secure_16.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "http://*/*"
    ]
```

}

**Description:**
When the page loads I get this error when trying to open a new tab

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to `chrome.tabs` on an extenal injected site.

You need to pass a message to a `background` script and call `chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'http://www.sethjfreeman.com' });` from there.

Check **[Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)**.

Comment: It now says: content.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at content.js:1

Comment: Code: chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
});

Comment: I read on: one time passing. as i only need it to happen once